# ssh connects but fails to complete unless I pass the -t option

Tags: ssh, 16.10, session, sshd

I upgraded a headless system from 16.04 to 16.10 a few days ago.  Now when I try to ssh to the system, it connects, logs me partially in, but then hangs before I get a command prompt.  For example:

```
> ssh 192.168.1.9
stephane@192.168.1.9's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.10 (GNU/Linux 4.8.0-34-generic x86_64)

3 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Last login: Wed Jan 25 16:43:29 2017 from 192.168.1.25
(...hang...)
```

And then it hangs there forever.  But, if I specify a command to run with ssh it works fine.  For example:

```
> ssh 192.168.1.9 uptime
stephane@192.168.1.9's password: 
07:49:49 up 15:08,  1 user,  load average: 2.01, 1.79, 1.39
```

If I try to force it to run bash, it also hangs:

```
> ssh 192.168.1.9 /bin/bash
stephane@192.168.1.9's password: 
(...hang...)
```

But if I pass the `-t` option to ssh, then everything works!

```
> ssh -t 192.168.1.9
stephane@192.168.1.9's password: 
stephane@renard:~$ 
stephane@renard:~$ date
Thu Jan 26 07:54:19 PST 2017
stephane@renard:~$ uptime
 07:54:23 up 15:12,  2 users,  load average: 2.00, 1.92, 1.55
```

Anyone have thoughts on what is happening?

Comment: What do you have in ~/.bashrc`?